# C++ - std::map with an enum as key

Tags: c++, enums, syntax-error, stdmap

I'm currently trying to create an std::map to store the state of each key of the keyboard. I've created the following map to do it :

```
static std::map<enum MouseCode, enum InputState> mousePressedMap;
```

No problem here.

To register the states, I've created a function called by my main class :

```
    void Input::ReadUserInput(enum Input::MouseCode mouseCode, enum Input::InputState inputState) {
    mousePressedMap[mouseCode] = inputState;
}
```

And here I'm getting my problem : I got an error on the "[" of the *mousePressedMap* saying : no "[]" operator corresponds to those operands.
And I cannot either do :

```
    void Input::ReadUserInput(enum Input::MouseCode mouseCode, enum Input::InputState inputState) {
    mousePressedMap[MouseCode::LeftButton] = InputState::DOWN;
}
```

I got the same error.

Besides, I think the error doesn't come from my enumerations :

```
        /// <summary>
    /// <para>Enumeration to set parameters to the mouse buttons handling function. The mouse code defines which button has been called.</para>
    /// </summary>
    enum MouseCode {
        LeftButton = 0,
        MiddleButton = 1,
        RightButton = 2
    };
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Enumeration to set parameters to the mouse buttons handling function. The input state is the current state of the button</para>
    /// </summary>
    enum InputState {
        /// <summary>
        /// Just pressed.
        /// </summary>
        DOWN,
        /// <summary>
        /// Just released.
        /// </summary>
        UP,
        /// <summary>
        /// Was already pressed the last frame.
        /// </summary>
        PRESSED,
        /// <summary>
        /// Is not currently activated and wasn't the last frame.
        /// </summary>
        INACTIVE
    };
```

Can someone explain me why? I come from C# and Java languages where this syntax was perfectly working and it's quite strange that is not the case here.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1 :**
The error message is (in French, sorry...):
Erreur  C2679   '[' binaire : aucun opérateur trouvé qui accepte un opérande de partie droite de type 'InputsManagement::Input::MouseCode' (ou il n'existe pas de conversion acceptable)    Win7 DirectX    c:\users\maxime\desktop\directx tests\win7 directx\win7 directx\input.cpp   16

Comment: *I come from C# and Java languages where this syntax was perfectly working* -- First and foremost, do not use other languages as a model in writing C++ code.  Pretend that Java and C# do not exist.

Comment: "no "[]" operator corresponds to those operands." -- more than likely that the ***full*** error message explicitly lists the types of the operands, which will give you your answer.

Comment: The error is in French, that's why I didn't posted it here.

Comment: @troopy28 You can still post it though

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://ideone.com/uq0oAB). The shown code compiles just fine. This question fails to provide a [mcve] for the problem.

Comment: Sorry. My first post here. I'm in a specific namespace and it seems to be the source of the error. I added it to your example and it now doesn't compile. You can see it here : http://pastebin.com/DTrj92LR

Comment: That's because you forgot to use the namespace when declaring the `std::map`, in your pastebin. This is fundamental C++. Again, once properly fixed, [unable to reproduce](https://ideone.com/4O9nZy). Compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the purpose of the code is to map the values 0, 1, and 2 into other values? Use an array, indexed by the `MouseCode` values.